# Run macros once Word doc is opened

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to run a few macros processes once I open my word doc. Is there any way I can run all of it automatically once I open the document? Thanks.

Comment: Doing a quick Google search I found this https://www.lifewire.com/run-autoexec-macros-open-word-3539955 Have you already tried it?

Answer (score 3):

If the macro should run when the document is opened, name the macro `AutoOpen`.

In order to run a macro when creating a new document from a template, name the macro `AutoNew`.

The information in [this article](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DocumentEvents.htm) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a sub with this name "Document_Open()" it will run whoever document opens.

```
Sub document_open()
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: This needs to be in the ThisDocument module to run with this name.

Answer (score 0):

Under the project tab in the VBA editor I use:

```
Private Sub Document_open()
'insert your macros directly or call them In here
End Sub
```

The document will need to be saved as a macro enabled document (.docm) for this to work.